# How to convert html code to php when inserting in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an HTML table which is generated from MySQL DB... works so far.
I tried to insert an "update" button which selects the DB id of each row...

the one with the "->" is the one, that should generate the href:

What I get is: `<a href"update.php?id=`  instead of `<a href"update.php?id=[id]`

Here is my code-snippet:

```
while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array( $db_erg, MYSQL_ASSOC))
      {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align=\"center\">". $zeile['vorname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=\"center\">". $zeile['nachname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=\"center\">". $zeile['gender'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=\"center\">". $zeile['gamertag'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=\"center\">". $zeile['mail'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=\"center\">". $zeile['age'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=\"right\">". $zeile['rank'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=\"right\">". $zeile['prime'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=\"right\">". $zeile['gametime'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=\"right\">". $zeile['msg'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=\"right\">". $zeile['status'] . "</td>";
  ->    echo "<td>". "<a href=\"update.php?id=\"".$zeile['id'].">update"."</a>"."</td>";
```

Any ideas?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
echo '<td><a href="update.php?id='.$zeile["id"].'">update</a></td>';
```

Comment: **works** ! Thank you bud !!!

Comment: Please always explain your solutions... even when they are simple/obvious to you or _most_ people.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use curly braces for this purpose. like below

```
echo "<td><a href='update.php?id={$zeile['id']}'>update</a></td>";
```

or you can use,

```
echo "<td><a href='update.php?id=".$zeile['id']."'>update</a></td>";
```

Comment: **works** ! Thank you so much ! Its much better with the braces !

Comment: yeah. with curly braces its looks neat.